# Firefox Tabs JSON Error #sessiondata

Tags: json, firefox, tabs

Had a load of important tabs open in FireFox, recovered my sessiondata however it wont open my tabs in FF. Using jsoneditoronline.org and I keep getting the error -

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
...ta":{"#sessionData":"{\"windows\":[{\"ta
-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
```

My interpretation of all of this is that after `"formdata"`: it should display something to the effect of `{}}],"index":1,"hidden":false,"attributes"`

however in my file it shows

```
"formdata":{"#sessionData":"{\"windows\":[{\"tabs\":[{\"entries\":[{\"url\":\"
```

Dont know much about coding so I'm not sure how to proceed with this issue.

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You JSON file is malformed, but from this little section, we really can't see why. Are you able to upload the whole file and post a link? Try pastebin.com

Comment: I'd prefer not to as it does contain all of my browsing history. Is there any other way?

Comment: Solved - For those struggling with this issue themselves I ended up going through the sessiondata.js file and manually extracting all of the links. A laborious task but worked just fine all the same

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

> For those struggling with this issue themselves, I ended up going through the sessiondata.js file and manually extracting all of the links. A laborious task but worked just fine all the same